# What are touch functions for in NSResponder?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I implemented an NSViewController. I noticed it has some touch functions like touchBeganWithEvent: from the NSResponder. I understand those functions will respond to my finger tap on iOS, but what are they for on Mac OS? They don't respond to mouse clicks. Only mouseDown: and the like will respond to mouse clicks.

Comment: couldn't these come from a trackpad?

Comment: Yea they do. Thanks. You answered my question. I did not know cocoa distinguishes mouses events and trackpad events.

Comment: glad that answered your question. in addition, here is the docs link which explain the whole thing. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingTouchEvents/HandlingTouchEvents.html

Comment: Yes, you need to set `view.acceptsTouchEvents = true` also.